# Summer running is slow. Am I getting slower because of this?

Tags: running, long-distance-running, speed, temperature

Help, summer running in 83-93 deg F (28-34 deg C) and 60-80 %RH stinks. **Update: Actually this was usually 78-83 def F at +95% RH in the mornings.** I want to get faster, but literally I cannot run fast in the summer. Except for short distances like 5k its impossible to see improvement over time during the summer. My question is whether or not I'll get faster at marathon length distances even though I'm not running long distances or medium length distances at a fast pace. Though the effort level is the same.

Another way to phrase this question is:

To gain long distance speed must you physically attain similar speeds or are there other modes you body can be in that is slower but will improve your speed?

Update -----------------------------------------------

I got slower due to the lack of time out on my feet and lack of water + nutrition. Plus refusing to stop to get water or some food... This has changed over July, August, and September. Though times are slow I know Im getting faster, and on a few recent mornings when the dew point dropped, or maybe there was some wind, I hit some PRs!

So the body acclimated and improved just in time to start training for Florida's marathon season!

Comment: Have you tried running while wearing soaking wet t-shirts? You then need to carry one or two water bottles with you, to keep it wet. All the water that then evaporates is what you will sweat less.

Comment: @CountIblis Havent tried that but I think I might. Thanks.

Comment: See http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16405/benefits-on-running-completely-soaked for reasons that may not be the best of ideas. It also will not help on the humidity question since you're just adding more liquid to the immediate environment. Unfortunately, I do not have a direct answer to your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information in the answer to a question on [the benefits on the benefits of running in the heat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6832/8039), you may indeed be reaping some benefits. [At least one study shows](http://uonews.uoregon.edu/archive/news-release/2010/10/heat-acclimation-benefits-athletic-performance-hot-and-cool-conditions):

> Heat acclimation improves the body’s ability to control body temperature, improves sweating and increases blood flow through the skin, and expands blood volume allowing the heart to pump more blood to muscles, organs and the skin as needed.

The athletes showed an improvement of up to 7% in runners when said runners went back to cooler environments due to their advances in thermoregulation.

Comment: In the study they say that the normal workout routine should still be done. If its not possible to meet the same paces as the normal workout routine demands then is there still a gain in performance?

Comment: I would imagine that you are still adapting to the greater heat, which will aid you in keeping cool when you're back to normal temperatures. As long as you're putting your full effort in, not just saying "Meh, too hot" and heading back in, it should help even if you're a bit slower.